# access to "Opera PMS" Oracle database

Tags: oracle

Do someone know how to access the database used by the Opera PMS software ? Is there a general answer for all Oracle database... the only info i found was about this command 
`sqlplus hr/my_hr_password@host_computer_name` 
is SQL plus installed with all Oracle software ? My goal is to make batch file, find some data in the Remote Database that had just been created by Opera PMS, save them on my local drive to a text file for the next step... Any clue will be very helpfull ... i 'm total noob in DB and dont want to mess up the system (i'm lazy employee but want to keep that one :-)) Blessed love

Answer (score 0):

If Oracle wanted developers to have programmatic access to the Opera data then they would provide an API for that. They don't. Opera PMS does an export function, OPP_EXP Export Files, but apparently [it's a chargeable extra](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53533_01/opera_5_05_00_core_help/export_files.htm). How very Oracle:)

Basically if your company pays for OPP_EXP Export Files you should use that. If they don't then attempting to get data out of the database by your own means would probably jeopardise your company's license agreement (although I agree it would be unlikely that Oracle would ever find out).

Comment: what mean chargeable extra? i'had seen this link before post here but what i understood of it is that was something on Opera side... I mean i cant send this command to Opera by the Terminal ? Yes/No ? How? When you say "get data by your own" you mean with sql plus? does it work with the database used by Opera?

Comment: **caveat** I'm not an Opera expert, I'm just googling this stuff. Chargeable extra means your company must pay an additional license fee to get that functionality. SQL\*Plus is an Oracle client function: apparently it is bundled with the Opera installation, for DBA operations.

Comment: Ok so sql seems the way to go ...  but  will need the user/pass ... dont know if the boss will let me in :-) For the chargeable extra i think it in it cause i can save doc from DB for printing... but how coulld i launch those task from the CLI? cmd or python. Is it even possible ... . thats why i look forward with sql+..